# How to print 4 byte Unicode character in Windows C++ console app?

Tags: c++, windows, console-application, windows-console, unicode-string

How to print ["" emoji](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+1F469) (Unicode code 1F469) in Windows console app using C++?

In example below I followed [Printing UTF-8 Text to the Windows Console](https://blogs.msmvps.com/gdicanio/2017/08/22/printing-utf-8-text-to-the-windows-console/).

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <io.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main()
{
    _setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT);
    std::wcout << L"face: \n";
    return 0;
}
```

However it only prints two questionmarks:

[image: console screenshot - two questionmarks].

"Command Prompt" (`cmd.exe`) app can't render this char so I'm using [Windows Terminal](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/windows-terminal-preview/9n0dx20hk701) that can render it:

[image: rendered face emoji in Windows Terminal]

Comment: There are couple of downvotes, could you please share what you find wrong with this question and recommendation how to approve it?

Answer (score 1):

The Windows Console cannot display characters outside of Plane 0.  The Windows Terminal was designed to improve on the limitations of the Windows Console.

Further reading: [How to use unicode characters in Windows command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388490/how-to-use-unicode-characters-in-windows-command-line/47843552#47843552)